# Required for Publishing

Tags: nodes

For my drupal I want an article always to have an image when it's published, however the authors do no have the rights to upload images (due to copyrighting issues, I only let this be done by a few people who have access to our photo partner, just to be sure that people don't download images from google)

So I want the image field to be required when publishing, but if I put it on required, then the authors have to fill it in during the draft as well, and they don't have the access for it.

I found the following module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/required_for_pub

But it requires a module "content" which I can't seem to find anywhere.
Does anyone have a suggestion for me?

Thank you very much

Comment: Is your website Drupal 6 or 7? The module you linked is for Drupal 6 only.

Comment: It's Drupal 7. You can see in the 'view all releases' that there is also a Drupal 7 module, but it's in dev.

PS: if you know another module, that's fine by me too, I don't exactly need this 1, any module who can make a field required only when publishing will do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the required by role module: https://www.drupal.org/project/required_by_role to make sure the publishers have to add an image. The downside is publishers will need to upload an image, even when not publishing.

Comment: Thank you Maarten, this is perfect for me.
You've helped me a lot!